# How to trigger email when celery worker goes down?

Tags: python, cron, celery, django-celery

I have configured django celery with rabbitmq in my server. Currently I am having only one node for my tasks.

I have tried with celery-flower, events, celerycam, etc. for monitoring the the worker/tasks status and it worked well.

My Problem is:-

I want to send mail notification if worker goes down for some reason.

I thought of creating cron job and running every 5 mins and check the status of worker(not sure this the correct way)

Is there any other extensions or other way to do this without cron??

Answer (score 1):

Run your workers using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). There's an [example](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/3.1/extra/supervisord/supervisord.conf) in the documentation. Then, take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/241721/get-notification-from-supervisord-when-a-job-exits) answer for how to send an email when the worker process goes down.